# Trim whitespace from DataTable cells with Linq

Tags: linq

This piece of code works to trim all spaces in each datacell of each datarow.
How can I get this code:

```
var dataRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var row in dataRows)
{
     var cellList = row.ItemArray.ToList();
     row.ItemArray = cellList.Select(x => x.ToString().Trim()).ToArray();
}
```

into one line of code so I don't have to loop through each row? Something like this but it doesn't work:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(y => y.ItemArray.ToList()).Select(x => x.ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: To clarify since it reads like there is a misconception: using linq or one line of code in any other form will still loop through each row. It might not be explicitly using a foreach but it will be. I guess following on from this is the question of why you want to do this? The above code seems perfectly adequate and readable, more so than it probably would be via linq...

Comment: Chris, I guess the real reason was to see if it could be done.  I agree that the initial code is more readable and will leave it at that.   Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you love LINQish stype:

```
  dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList()
        .ForEach(row =>
        {
            var cellList = row.ItemArray.ToList();
            row.ItemArray = cellList.Select(x => x.ToString().Trim()).ToArray();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

With linq you can't change item values finally you should run for loop (or foreach) to change fields value.

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
var iq = obj from dataTable.asEnumerable() select new{
PersonName = a.Field<string>("PersonName"),
PersonID = a.Field<decimal>("PersonID"),
ParticipantString = a.Field<string>("DisplayString"),
PersonUserName = d.Field<string>("UserName")
}
```